# NullPointerException on getWritableDatabase() on Persisten Storage

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, persistent-storage

I keep getting the same error on two activities whenever I attempt to write or read from the database.

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The error is thrown when this method is called:

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

Which is contained in this class:

```
public class DriverController {

// Database fields
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_COLUMN_ID,
        MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_COLUMN_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_COLUMN_DRIVERNO };

public DriverController() {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

The MySQLiteHelper class is based on this tutorial. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

All the same, any assistance you can offer will be greatly appreciated. I'm already behind schedule.

Comment: Initialize `context` object properly as *Pozzo Apps* said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
```

instance `context` is null so initialize `context` object before using it or pass `context` as parameter from calling activty as

```
public DriverController(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}
```

You have to pass `context` from calling `actvity` to `DriverController` constructor because `context` is available only in activity class

For reference see `CommentsDataSource` class used in the [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) you provide.

Answer (score 2):

in this line `dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);` you are passing a null context, that's cause `getWritableDatabase()` to throw a `NullPointerException`.

You need a valid context.